# Pathname to the image field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model which has Image field to be uploaded. It has a foreign key reference to another class.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

def upload_to(path, attribute):

    def upload_callback(instance, filename):
        return '%s%s/%s' % (path, unicode(slugify(getattr(instance, attribute))), filename)

    return upload_callback


class Data(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    typeOfProperty = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    typeOfPlace = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    ownerName = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    
class ImageData(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Data, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_to('image/', 'ownerName'),blank=True,null=True)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.property.ownerName
```

I have refered this [This Web Page](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/#comment-625) to create a dynamic field for images to be stored.

My doubt is can I use the `onerName` as the attribute in (as the ownerName is in the super class) :

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_to('image/', 'ownerName'),blank=True,null=True)
```

How does Django consider this request that is need to be served?

Please can anyone explain me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'ownerName'` is not going to work. It's quite complicated to do the definition of what you want to save in the ImageField directly. Maybe you should do something like this:

```
def upload_to(path):

    def upload_callback(instance, filename):
        return '%s%s/%s' % (path, unicode(slugify(instance.property.ownerName), filename)

    return upload_callback
```

If you really want to make it as dynamic as possible you have to pass something like `'property.ownerName'` to the function, split the string, retrieve attrtibute `property` from `ImageData` instance and then attribute `ownerName` from its foreign key instance.

Though I think this makes things way to complicated and you better define extra functions for different use cases.